# Mixing Http and Websockets in Python Quart

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio, quart

So my application needed to employ both a RESTful backend and a websockets backend. So I switched my API from Flask to Quart. However, even when following the docs to word the issue remains.

```py
@app.websocket("/gen-image")
async def gen_image_ws():
    while True:
        data = await websocket.receive()
        if data == "Hello":
            await websocket.send("World")


@app.route("/gen-image", methods=["GET", "POST"])
async def gen_image():
    ...
```

But I get a bad handshake error

```
Starting WebSocket connection to ws://localhost:5500/gen-image
websocket: bad handshake
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What client are you using?

Comment: My production client is flutter, but I have tried everything from cli tools like claws and httpx in python.

Comment: Could you post the raw HTTP headers sent and received?

Also is 5500 a typo? Quart usually uses 5050